# open error - No such file or directory

Tags: perl, file, debugging

I am using `File::Find` to run through a directory tree and when I try to open the current file for reading I get `No such file or directory`. This happens with ALL files in the directory tree.

Here's the sub I use in the `find()`:

```
sub {
    if (-d) {
        return;
    }
    if (-f) {
        my $file = ${File::Find::name};
        open (my $IN, '<', '$file') or die "$!\n";
        while (<$IN>) {
            ### Do some formatting.
        }
        close $IN;
    }
}
```

It fails in the line:

```
open (my $IN, '<', '$file') or die "$!\n";
```

I thought it's a matter of links maybe, but even with `follow => 1` option I get this error.

By the way, without `follow` the error I get is on the first file of the first directory I find and with it, the error is on the last file of the last directory (but in both cases, it's on the first file inspected by `File::Find`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Apparently, replacing the single quotes with double quotes in the `open` line, or even better, not using any quotes, did the trick. The string literal `'$file'` produces the string `$file`, and there's clearly no file with this name.

Comment: `open (my $IN, '<', '$file')` tries to open a file that's literally named `dollar-f-i-l-e` because the single ticks `'` don't interpolate variables. As you already noticed you can either use double quotes `"` (which interpolates) or (even better) don't use any of them and simply write `$file`.

Comment: @PerlDuck as you can see, I wrote it in my answer :) Also, writing just `$file` is better, can't believe I missed that option!

Comment: @PerlDuck No reason for you to delete it, it's ok